# I can't get value from script to jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, android, jsoup

I want to code get value stream but fail.

How to get value stream : http://123.30.215.65/hls/4545780bfa790819/5/3/d836ad614748cdab11c9df291254cf836f21144da20bf08142455a8735b328ca/dnR2MQ==_m.m3u8 using Jsoup ?

```html
   <html>
 <head>
  <style>html,body{margin:0;padding:0;background:#000;;}</style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clappr/latest/clappr.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
 </head>      
 <body> 
  <div style="width: 100%;"> 
  </div> 
  <div id="player"></div> 
  <script>
 player = new Clappr.Player({source: "http://123.30.215.65/hls/4545780bfa790819/5/3/d836ad614748cdab11c9df291254cf836f21144da20bf08142455a8735b328ca/dnR2MQ==_m.m3u8",
   parentId: '#player',
   width: '100%', height: "100%",
      hideMediaControl: true,
      autoPlay: true
             }); 
 </script>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Java code me :

```java
Elements script = doc.select("script");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("player = new Clappr.Player(\\(\"source:{\", \"(.*)\", false\\)");
                                                    //  ^^ is the capturing group
String url = "";

for (Element element : script) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(element.data());
    if (m.find()){
        url = m.group(1);
    }
}
System.out.println(url);
```

Comment: Try `Pattern.compile("player = new Clappr.Player\\(\\{source: \"(.*?)\"")`.

Comment: @saka1029 You should probably make that an answer

Comment: i try but not success :(

Comment: i try code : Pattern.compile("player = new Clappr\\.Player\\(\\{source: \"(http:.*)\",.*");  but not success

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this in your code,

```
String ResultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("source:\\s[\"](.*?[^\\\\])[\"]", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

This works like a charm..! :)

Comment: yeah. thank u support but dont understand subjectString . please support

Comment: @XuânMai you don't understand `subjectString` then you can quick research on [`matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)) function of `Pattern` class to understand it. In this situation then the `subjectString` is your `element.data()` above. You will need to compile @Shankara 's answer with your loop

Comment: @XuânMai, subjectString is the script value which you get from the Element